# Why is my android camera crashing when I try to add callback buffer?

Tags: android, callback, camera, buffer, android-camera

I am trying to add a callback buffer to my camera app but I am really struggling right now. What I did is that I first added a preview callback for my camera once the surface texture is available. So in my `onSurfaceTextureAvailable()` I did this:

```
mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(null);
mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(getPreviewCallback());
// After allocating the preview callback I start the preview
mCamera.startPreview();
```

The `getPreviewCallback()` just looks like this:

```
private PreviewCallback getPreviewCallback() {
    if (mPreviewCallback == null) {
        mPreviewCallback = new PreviewCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                // Here I would like to do something later on
            }

        };
    }
    return mPreviewCallback;
}
```

Now, the point where my camera "dies" is when I add the callback buffer. I do this on a button click. So when my button gets clicked this gets called:

```
mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[FRAME_BYTE_SIZE]);
```

where `FRAME_BYTE_SIZE` is calculated elsewhere (on my nexus 4 is it 384000)
The message from the logcat is this one:

```
04-08 13:46:41.049: W/CameraBase(7884): Camera service died!
04-08 13:46:41.049: W/CameraBase(7884): mediaserver's remote binder Camera object died
04-08 13:46:41.049: E/Camera(7884): Error 100
```

Why is this happening? Any ideas?

Comment: Please, let me know your ideas! Even if you are not really sure